# Android wear type input (without speak)

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

In the previous version of Android emulator I was able to type text (No need to speak). But for the latest version, I can't type anymore.

My problem is sometimes I don't speak english well, so testing is so crazy with me. (Speaking many times).

So I need the easiest way to make the input(on the dialog speech recognize) on Android Wear (while testing on emulator.)

Comment: What previous version was this working correctly where you were able to use text?

Comment: It's Android Wear Preview version.